# jQuery: How to find an element inside of hashchange event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, handlers, hashchange

A web-page has some links:

```
<a href="#example-hash-1" class="link">example-1</a>
<a href="#example-hash-2" class="link">example-2</a>
<a href="#example-hash-n" class="link">example-n</a>
```

Clicking any on them it runs an event of hashchange and we going to handle it:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(event){

    // Is it possible (inside this handler) to find out which of a.link was clicked?

});
```

Or, is there another way to do it?

Comment: For your case [event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) will do it.

Comment: and `location.hash;` ? i.e.: `var hash = location.hash;`

Answer (score 1):

While I believe adding click listeners to the actual links would be best, you could also search for the element that would have changed the hash as such:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(event){
    $('a[href$='+window.location.hash+']').action();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use onclick as an attribute in the  tag or you could use the .click() event through jQuery. I think that will accomplish the same as the window on hashchange.

Answer (score 0):

`event.target` will hold which element triggered the event.

I can't check at the moment, but I believe that `this` also binds.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(event){

    var hash = location.hash;
    var $this = $(hash);
    alert($this.html());
});
```